# Spring Rest Application is not starting (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, model-view-controller

Here is the link for the repository where's the API:

https://github.com/moreiravictor/postAPI

Console prints me the following error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ruivoo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ruivoo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.7/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanUtils.java:359)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getNames(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:196)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at br.com.espatodea.postAPI.App.main(App.java:9)
```

Comment: "*`See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation`*"

Comment: correct the build path. right now only src is in the build path. remove src from build path and change it to src/main/java. do maven clean and build.

Comment: Both did not work, the error keeps the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the SLF4J version conflict and the stack trace explains this more than clearly. The 4th line says:

> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

One of the offered solution is to exclude SLF4J from Lombok:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

However, I see one of the dependencies is explicitly `/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.7`, so I'd remove this one.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but now I have this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
 at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:162)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run [...]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I decided to go to spring initializr and create a new project with the right dependencies, it was easier this way. Your answer was taking me to the right direction, but something else was wrong.